# Get Azure Devops Build ID in React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops

I am busy creating a React App whereby I would like to get the Azure Devops Build Id and Display it in a component of mine.

This is my pipeline. I have never used Azure Devops before. I know there is predefined variables and i need to use `Build.BuildId` in my react project, How do i use it?

here is my Version.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import '../components/Common/CoolButton/styles.css'




export const Version = () => {
    return (
        <a className="My_Style">{Build.BuildId}</a>
    );
}
```

and my webpack

```
reactWebComp.register(Version, 'react-version', [], {}, { useShadowDOM: false });
```

Any sort of documentation or anything would be really appreciated, I just need to display the BuildID

[image: Pipeline]

Comment: try with `{process.env.Build.BuildId}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [replace tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task to your pipeline and let it replace the variable in your version.js.